# Sum area of multiple polygons of same layer that are all contained within different polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, shape-area

I have multiple polygons of the same layer that are all contained within another polygon of a different layer (please see the example below- picture is of Great Barrier Island and surrounding islands, in New Zealand).

[image: I want to sum the pink area contained within the green area.]
I am hoping to find a way to sum the area of the pink polygons (government owned land) that are contained within the larger green polygons (the actual island projection) in ArcMap. As can be seen in the figure, there are multiple islands, each of which contain varying amounts of government owned land.

Ideally, I am looking for a way to calculate this information for many islands within the New Zealand archipelago. If there is a way to calculate this en masse, that'd be great, but if it has to be done manually, that's okay too.

I am relatively new to GIS and ArcMap. Also, I am proficient in R (but not Python) if that can assist the analysing process.

Comment: Assign your islands unique names if none. Compute areas of public lands if none. Spatially join land parcels to island s. Summarise areas of parcels using island Id as case field. Join summary table back to islands table.